# How does show total of up and down votes work?

Tags: support, reputation

I have over 1000 reputation which means that I should be able to "Show total up and down vote counts"... I'm not sure exactly how this works. I know for example [my recent answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29424/canning-tomato-sauce/29425#29425) has at least 1 down vote, but when I look at the vote count it just shows 4 up votes... How do I see the number of up and down? (Should be 5 up 1 down.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You click on the number once. Then you see not a single number any more, but a green number and below it a red number. The green number is the amount of positive votes, the red is the amount of negative votes.

[image: vote]

The default view still shows the sum. You have to click each time you want to see the up and down counts on a single answer or question.